# How to schedule a Job for every 1st Tuesday of the Month on Google Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a pre-determined function using an HTTP response on Google Cloud Scheduler. I'm having issues scheduling the event for the proper time though.

What I have currently is `30 10 ? * 2#1` in order to try and schedule it for the first Tuesday of any month at 10:30, but I keep getting "invalid format."

Any help?